# What's the correct tense?

Tags: tenses

I came across a sentence that said:

*For example, Philips Hue lights recently added one. Previously they would come on when power is restored.*

Should it be ***is restored*** or ***was restored***?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context of either the sentence before or after the sentence you've written though by just the sentence above "was restored" sounds much more plausible as the word "previously" indicates something which has already happened while instead using "is restored" indicates that which is happening now,
 e.g. the power is now restored
is "now" restored

e.g. the power was restored
It was restored which means it has been restored sometime "before" now

Comment: I have difficulty in understanding this answer.